Count files and folders in a SharePoint Document Library
Is there a way to get the total number of files and folders in a SharePoint document library?
I mean, the total number of files and total number of folders from the library, like Windows Explorer does display when you click on the properties of a folder.
Actually, there is a number that mentions "items", what does it mean, "item"? file or folder?
Here is some code I tried to execute, but it gave non relevant results, I am not sure how to test if that is true
$siteUrl = "https://constoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite"
$listName = "myDocumentLibrary"

Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx -Url $siteUrl -Interactive

$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -PageSize 5000 -ScriptBlock { param($items) $items }

$totalFiles = 0
$totalFolders = 0

foreach ($item in $listItems) {
    if ($item.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File") {
        $totalFiles++
    } elseif ($item.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder") {
        $totalFolders++
    }
}

Write-Output "Total files :  $totalFiles"
Write-Output "Total folders: $totalFolders"

